# How compareTo(Object o) method exeutes in java?

Tags: java, collections

I am having confusion over execution of the `compareTo` method in Java.

```
public int compareTo(Employee emp)
{
    int i = this.DeptId - emp.DeptId;

    if (i > 0)
        return 1;
    else if (i < 0)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

This method would be called through an object of Employee class, so first time when it would be called, `this.DeptId` would be object's `DeptId` and `emp.DeptId` also this object's `DeptId`.

When this method is called second time, then again it should be called with second object, so again it should `return 0;` but this is not the case.

I can understand I don't know how `compareTo` method is called in Java. Could anyone please explain or give me a reference to get this correct?

I am using this code to test it:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(1, 11, "mfg", "Rajesh");
Employee e2 = new Employee(2, 12, "mfg", "Arka");       
Employee e3 = new Employee(3, 11, "pes" ,"Sanjeev");
list.add(e1);
list.add(e2);
list.add(e3);
Collections.sort(list);
```

I don't understand what `Collections.sort(list);` is doing.

How it calls `compareTo` second time like `e2.compareTo(e1);` is the place of my doubt.

Comment: What code are you using to test it?

Comment: My apologies - We should not downvote a question  just because it seems trivial. The OP has a genuine doubt/confusion and he is asking it. I see no point in downvoting..

Comment: Refer [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html) site

Comment: This is a good and interesting question, and this close reason doesn't apply.  The question is not about a problem with the code.  It's only a question about what the `sort` method is actually doing.  So this close reason should never have been applied to this question.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: [Collection.sort(list)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) will sort the elements in the list by their natural order using the specified CompareTo method.

Answer (score 3):

If you call `employee1.compareTo(employee2)`, `this` is `employee1` and `emp` is `employee2`.

In other words, `this.DeptId-emp.DeptId` would be `employee1.DeptId-employee2.DeptId`.

Answer (score 1):

**so first time when it would be called,this.DeptId would be object's DeptId and emp.DeptId also this object's DeptId.**

This statement is wrong. Anytime the `compareTo` method is called it will pass in another object as a parameter of the method not the same object itself.

Comment: It means Collections.sort(...); invokes compareTo(Object o) like e1.compareTo(e2) and if e1.DeptId is greater then second time it would be e1.compareTo(e3);  Did i get it clear?

Answer (score 0):

Compareto method in java is basically used to compare two strings like

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String str1 = "Strings are immutable";
      String str2 = "Strings are immutable";
      String str3 = "Integers are not immutable";

      int result = str1.compareTo( str2 );
      System.out.println(result);

      result = str2.compareTo( str3 );
      System.out.println(result);

      result = str3.compareTo( str1 );
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

**output:**

```
0
10
-10
```

here the `str1.compareTo( str2 );` compares string one with two i.e str1 will be your `this` object and based on the difference between them returns and integer. If the two strings are equal it returns 0.

```
a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
```

Check this links http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm